# Cannot set variable value to a dash in zsh

Tags: zsh

If I run the following code:

```
foo='-'
```

The variable is empty

```
echo "'$foo'"
> ''
```

I've tried several ways of setting the variable, none of which work:

```
foo="-"
foo=-
foo='-'
eval 'foo="-"'
foo="$(echo "-")"
```

Why can I not set a variable in ZSH to `-`?

Comment: Works for me, in 5.4.2. Try `typeset -p foo` to narrow down whether it's actually the setting that fails, or the expansion/display.

Comment: Please confirm you try `echo "'$foo'"` each time. If you kept trying `echo "$foo"` and switched to `echo "'$foo'"` only *after* `foo="$(echo "-")"` then it would be a reproducible scenario and the reason would be that Zsh's `echo` treats `-` specially. See [*Why is `printf` better than `echo`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` is a better way to test what `$foo` expands to.

Comment: I also had this problem and was really confused. It turns out it was due to `echo`'s special handling of `-` in zsh as @KamilMaciorowski mentioned above. Using `echo "'$foo'"` or `printf "%s\n" "$foo"` works as expected.